# How to create a complete datetime from a month and year passed as parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I want to let a user select a month and a year in a report from textbox and use these parameters to create first day in the month and the last one for my server parameters 'DateFrom' and 'DateTo', so I can use these as filters.

I've tried:

```
@DateFrom           DATETIME,
@DateTo             DATETIME,
@Month              NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
@Year               NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL

AS
  BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

SET @DateFrom = '1.' & @Month & @Year
SET @DateTo = DATEADD(m, 1, DATEADD(s, -1, @DateFrom))
```

Any help would be aprreciated.

Comment: have you looked at `DATEFROMPARTS`, link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql)

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Why are you using bitwise operators (`&`) when working with dates and strings?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Server 2008, MSMS 2016

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
SET @DateFrom = SELECT CAST(@Year + '-' + @Month + '-' + '01' AS DATE)
SET @DateTo = DATEADD(m, 1, DATEADD(s, -1, @DateFrom))
```

Comment: Try to print the dates and check what dates are being set.

Comment: I've caught it with Profiler. Output seems OK:
exec SSRS_SP_Report_TicketerSales @DateFrom='2017-05-01 00:00:00',@DateTo='2017-05-31 00:00:00'

Comment: So date is getting set correctly. Then please check rest of your procedure for issues. One more thing use DateTime instead of Date so that DateTo should be covered till 23:59:59 instead of 00:00:00. Since dates are setting correctly, I guess you can accept this answer.